# how to get the vector-diagonal of a vector of nXn matrices in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have for example

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((100, 5, 5))
```

And I want

```
d = np.vector_diagonal(a)

assert d.shape == (100, 5)
```

Where `d[i, j]` corresponds to `a[i, j, j]`

How to do this with numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.diagonal(a, axis1=1, axis2=2)
```

Just need to select which axes are "the matrix" and which "vectorize the matrices"

The reduction will be done on the selected axes.